# How to get recordID of CKReference

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cloudkit

I'm using CloudKit and I have two record types. Record type B contains a CKReference to record type A. I'm not having any trouble getting record type B, including the CKReference data of record type A, but I can't figure out how to get the recordID from the CKReference record (record type A). Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recordID` is a property of `CKReference`. Fetch the value from the record for the reference, then access the `recordID` property on that value.

For example, if your reference value was named "AReference":

`recordB[@"AReference"].recordID`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I just read that in the documentation 5 minutes ago. I didn't notice it before!